# Как прижать футер к низу?

Tags: css, css3

Я не как не могу прижать футер к низу. В чем может быть проблема?

При маленьком разрешении экрана он прижат к низу, но когда уменьшаем масштаб страницы он не остается внизу.

```
#footer {
position:relative;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}
```

[image: 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20%5bcss%5d  |  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20%5bcss%5d

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Надо прописать абсолютное позиционирования к футеру.

```
position: absolute;
```

Но вообще лучше с этим не играться, и перейти в конце концов на flex-box, можно начать с bootstrap 4.

Comment: Я уже пробовал прописать position:absolute; если я это прописываю то он всегда сверху страницы

Comment: Пропишите контенту position: relative;

Comment: Я попробовал но тут уже проблема с body: [картинка](https://image.prntscr.com/image/bMV-C330QlKrdQJFufNd6g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю почему `min-height: 100%;` не действовало.

Решил проблему прописав min-height: 100vh:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```